# Use less files in django templates

Tags: python, django, less

I've got some trouble to load and compile a less file in my django template.
First of all I load one main less file in my header.html :

**header.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/bootstrap-.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/select2-3.5.2/select2.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/lib/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/static/less/style.less" type="text/css">
```

The less is loading without any problem.
Now I want to load specific less file for a specific django app. For example, I have an app named "helpdesk" and I want to do something like this :

**helpdesk.html**

```
{% block header %}
{{ block.super }}
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/static/helpdesk/less/style_helpdesk.less" type="text/less">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/helpdesk/js/helpdesk.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

In this case, less is not loading or compiling. I tried to use some django modules like **django-compressor** or **django-static-precompiler** but I was not able to make them work.

I looked after this for hours so any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think less files can be used like that. They need to be compiled to css using lessc or a similar tool (like less.js).

Comment: @Brobin I agree with you but I'm wondering why my less files in "header.html" are compiled and not the others. This makes no sense to me

Comment: Your `type` is different for the less files in the header and helpdesk. `text/css` and `text/less`.

Comment: @Brobin I already tried to change this but it doesn't work...

Comment: What are you using to compile the less? Is the problem with the less or that the entire template is not loading correctly?

Comment: I have no idea how the less files are compiled, I have just installed less on my linux server, put the lib files in my project. My template is loading correctly, only the css is missing.

Comment: Ah. first you need to compile the less. This will create a css file that you can use. In the command line, do this int he folder that contains the less: `lessc style_helpdesk.less > style_helpdesk.css`. Then change your `link` to reference the css files, not the less files.

Comment: This works great but I don't want to have to compile it again manually everytime I change the file... So that's why I wanted the files to compile automatically like the one in the "header.html"

Comment: I found out the solution. Thanks anyway @Brobin for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I retried to use the **django-compressor** module and it worked !

I followed this link which is well explained : http://marklmiddleton.com/2013/using-less-with-django-on-heroku/